# How can I get defined methods based on webservice url

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic

How can I dynamically get all declared methods from a webservice based only on his url?

Basicly I want the exact same thing as the WCF Test Client does. The list with all the methods and interface.

**EDIT**

Using the WSDL for getting the methods is a good idea, never thought of that.

However this raises the next problem. How can I invoke a method when all I have is it's name and the url for the service?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: I have tried using a default service reference and changing the endpoint address but without being able to know what the "client" will be in the new service reference it's impossible to create a instance or get a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language). The webservice client uses this, too.

Most likely there is a url that you can get the wsdl from. For WCF services, it's the url of the service (www.somesite.com\folder\servicename.svc) plus the `?wsdl` parameter:

> www.somesite.com\folder\servicename.svc?wsdl

Comment: I can get all methods based on this, but how can I invoke the methods if I want to without adding a service refence ? (I know.. this is basicly a new question).  See edit!

Comment: Why don't you look at the code generated as code-behind for the service reference? There's no magic, it's all normal C# code.

Comment: Because it is all dynamic.  I need to invoke methods of a random webservic which is "created" at runtime.

Comment: Then look at the generated code. You will need to do the same it does, just on the fly.